# Sublime Text auto unindent on tag close - file types

Tags: sublimetext3, auto-indent

How do I enable Sublime Text's xml auto indent features in alternate file types, other than .html and .xml?

Specifically, I want Sublime Text (ver 3.0) to auto indent my next line after an opening tag (example: typing `<p>`+enter should indent one level), and auto UNindent a closing tag when it auto completes it for me (example: typing `</` auto completes the closing tag, but should also unindent to the proper level).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To permanently open a custom file type using a specific syntax choose `View > Syntax > Open all with current extension as…` from the main menu and select XML.